# How can I use FB.ui to create unpublished post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ui

I have been trying to use fb.ui to create an unpublished post. Cant find any documentation for it. Is this possible with v2.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think you can do it with `FB.ui` dialogs (and scheduling is only possible for Pages anyway), but it is possible with `FB.api`:

```
const params = {
    access_token: <pageToken>,
    published: false,
    message: 'some text',
    scheduled_publish_time: <timestamp>
};

FB.api('/<pageid>/feed', params, (response) => {
    if (response && response.error) {

    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: Im able to do it with FB.api .. but wanted to use moods and checkins that comes with Fb.ui.

Comment: did you try to add those with FB.api? At least checkin (= adding a location) should be possible.

Comment: fb.ui gives me all the options build right into the dialog.. tagging friends, moods, locations.. anyways looks like its not possible to use fb.ui for this.

Comment: yes, scheduling is not possible with Fb.ui. btw, scheduling is not possible for user profile walls anyway, only for pages.